# Trying to make an array based on positive numbers from another array

Tags: c, arrays

Trying to make an array based on positive numbers of other array. What's the problem? Not working in the latex Xcode. Basically it`s supposed to be easy peasy, but I can`t figure out the problem. Any hints?

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 int main()
 {
    int size,i,n=0;
    puts("Enter the size of array <=40");
    scanf("%i",&size);

    float X[size], Y[n];
    puts("Enter the array");

    for (i=0; i<=size; i++) //entering the array and comparing and creating a  new one
    {
        scanf("%f",&X[size]);
        if (X[size]>=0)
        {
            Y[n]=X[size];
            n++;
        }  
    }

    i=0;
    for (n=0; i<=n; i++)
        printf("%f", Y[n]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _easy peasy_?  Hmmm.  Yeah, I like it.

Answer (score 0):

Your declaration of `Y[n]` is the problem. `n` is initialized to `0`. It should be `Y[size]`. Also your `for` loop body should be

```
 for (i = 0; i < size; i++) //entering the array and comparing and creating a  new one
{
    scanf("%f", &X[i]);
    if (X[i] >= 0)
    {
        Y[n] = X[i];
        n++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

trying to access X[size] is another problem (it seems X should not be an array at all)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int size, i, n=0;
    puts("Enter the size of array <=40");
    scanf("%i", &size);

    float X[size], Y[size];
    puts("Enter the array");

    for (i=0; i < size; ++i) {
        scanf("%f", &X[i]);
        if (X[i]>=0){
            Y[n++]=X[i];
        }
    }

    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
       printf("%f\n", Y[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get your code closer to your stated goal of ***easy peasy*** (your words, not mine) change code to include the following edits:

```
int size=80,i,n=80;//or something other than zero, i.e. values are use to create arrays later.
                   //must have some non 0 value or arrays will be useless
int n1 = 0;
//.......
float X[size], Y[n];
//.......
for (i=0; i<=size; i++) //entering the array and comparing and creating a  new one
{
    scanf("%f",&X[i]);
    if (X[i]>=0)
    {
        Y[n1]=X[i];
        n1++;
        if(n1 >= n) break;// n1 is the array index and must never be >= to n.
    }  
}
```

***The edits*** primarily address two problems.
***1)*** the problem that ***i*** is changing with the loop, while ***size*** was not.
***2)*** the problem that n is used to create an array with a size of zero, or the abilty to hold 0 `float` values.  You must create it with a size greater than zero if it is to contain any values.

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1:

When you declare your array with `float X[size], Y[n];`, the compiler reserves space for `size` floats in `X`, and for `n` floats in `Y` **according to the values of `size` and `n` when the statement is executed**. This allocation does not change just because you change the value of `n` later. Since `n` has the value of zero when the array `Y` is allocated, any attempt to access anything in that array is undefined behavior, there simply are no elements in that array.

Now, there are two easy ways to fix your code, as the other answers have already pointed out (I mainly wanted to add an explanation):

1. Computing the number of positive numbers beforehand, then executing `float Y[n]`, and finally doing the actual copying.
2. Just using the maximum possible number of positive numbers as the array size, i. e. saying `float X[size], Y[size];`.

Both methods will work, they simply have different tradeoffs. But I don't think, you are worried about the tradeoffs yet.

---

Problem 2:

Array indices in C always run from `0` to `size-1`, where `size` is the value you supplied when you allocated the array (as in `float foo[size];`). Accessing `foo[size]` is accessing one element **past the end of the array**, which is also undefined behavior.

As such, you need to change your loop condition from `for (i=0; i<=size; i++)` to `for(i = 0; i < size; i++)`.

---

Problem 3:

Oh, and, of course, you need to write each number into a different element of your array, i. e. change `X[size]` into `X[i]`.